# How to run Skype with Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, skype

I have installed Skype using the Software Center. I have the file on my desktop and I right clicked to see if I could run it as I had no icon and there isn't any way to run it (I am new to Linux) and need help any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

when you install an application in Ubuntu 12.10, you can open it by searching it in Unity Dash. To do that, use Windows key and just type Skype in it.

Answer (score 0):

Tto run Skype (if you have installed it), just type `skype` in the terminal. To open the terminal, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.